# What is the smallest possible valid PDF?

Tags: pdf, optimization, pdf-generation

Out of simple curiosity, having seen [the smallest GIF](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever), what is the smallest possible valid PDF file?

Comment: Depends on how you create it. Chances are that you'll be able to write a smaller one yourself (in an editor) than what an application would generate.

Comment: Try feeding "showpage" (w/o quotes) to ghostscript or ps2pdf.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  Taking it by the book, you can start off with this:

```
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj 2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj 3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>endobj
xref
0 4
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000053 00000 n
0000000102 00000 n
trailer<</Size 4/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
149
%EOF
```

which is 291 bytes of PDF joy.  Acrobat opens it, but it complains somewhat.  There is one page in it and it is 3/72" square, the minimum allowed by the spec.

However, Acrobat X doesn't even bother with the  cross reference table anymore, so we can take that out:

```
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj 2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj 3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>endobj
trailer<</Size 4/Root 1 0 R>>
```

Acrobat complains, but opens it.  Now we're at 178 bytes.
Turns out that you don't need that /Size in the trailer.  Now we're at 172:

```
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj 2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj 3 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>endobj
trailer<</Root 1 0 R>>
```

Turns out you don't need all those pesky /Type elements in your dictionaries:

```
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj<</Pages 2 0 R>>endobj 2 0 obj<</Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj 3 0 obj<</MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>endobj
trailer<</Root 1 0 R>>
```

Now we're at 138 bytes.

It also turns out that when the spec says "shall be an indirect reference" and /Count is required, and the header "must" be %PDF-1.0, they're making loose suggestions.  This is the smallest I could make it and have it openable in Acrobat X:

```
%PDF-1.
trailer<</Root<</Pages<</Kids[<</MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>]>>>>>>
```

70 bytes.

Now, my editor uses Windows newline discipline, but Acrobat accepts Windows, Mac, or Unix conventions, so by using a hex editor, I replaced the \r\n with \r and removed the last newline altogether, which leaves me with 67 bytes

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 0D 74 72 61 69 6C 65 72 3C 
3C 2F 52 6F 6F 74 3C 3C 2F 50 61 67 65 73 3C 3C 
2F 4B 69 64 73 5B 3C 3C 2F 4D 65 64 69 61 42 6F 
78 5B 30 20 30 20 33 20 33 5D 3E 3E 5D 3E 3E 3E 
3E 3E 3E
```

I tried taking off the last end dictionary (>>), but Acrobat wouldn't have that.  The PDF reading built-in to Google Chrome (FoxIt) won't open it.

As a PostScript (HA! See what I did there?), if you consent to Acrobat "repairing" the file, it bumps up to 3550 bytes, most of it optional metadata, but it leaves behind a number of clear spec violations.

Comment: *It also turns out that when the spec says "shall be an indirect reference" and /Count is required, and the header "must" be %PDF-1.0, they're making loose suggestions.* No, those aren't loose suggestions, those are requirements for validity. Even if some PDF viewers don't enforce them, not following them implies invalidity, and the OP asked for a valid PDF.

Comment: Accepted because answer starts off with the `minimum allowed by the spec` and then goes above and beyond. Great answer, thank-you! :)

Comment: plith, that's an awesome answer. Now, how about the smallest valid pdf with a line of text in it, like "Hello World".  I thought it would be as simple as adding { stream BT ("Hello World") ET endstream } but so far could not make Acrobat happy.

Comment: In fact, taking it "by the book" would require the Page to have a /Parent — this is what Adobe complains about, I believe.  See the "7.7.3.3 Page Objects" section in the standard.

Comment: Page having to have a parent is a bit of a pain because it sets up a circular reference.

Comment: That's the spec.  The graph of objects in PDF has cycles.

Comment: I needed a base64-representation of a PDF. So, if anyone is interested, here is the base64-string of the 138 bytes version: `JVBERi0xLjAKMSAwIG9iajw8L1BhZ2VzIDIgMCBSPj5lbmRvYmogMiAwIG9iajw8L0tpZHNbMyAw\nIFJdL0NvdW50IDE+PmVuZG9iaiAzIDAgb2JqPDwvTWVkaWFCb3hbMCAwIDMgM10+PmVuZG9iagp0\ncmFpbGVyPDwvUm9vdCAxIDAgUj4+Cg==`

Comment: ...and here's the base64-string version of the 67 byte version: `JVBERi0xLg10cmFpbGVyPDwvUm9vdDw8L1BhZ2VzPDwvS2lkc1s8PC9NZWRpYUJveFswIDAgMyAzXT4+XT4+Pj4+Pg==`

Comment: @towi Your base64-encoded version has `\n`s embedded in it, and when base64-decoded doesn't give the correct file contents.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Good to know for people who are not using an `\n`-agnostic decoder. I seem to be doing that, since `\n` is not one of the base64 chars.

Comment: I played around with this a bit, and if you instead use `1 0 obj<</Pages<</Kids[<</MediaBox[0 0 3 3]>>]>>>>endobj trailer<</Root 1 0 R>>` (only the trailer has to be indirect) the file will open in Chrome's viewer without complaint at only 87 bytes.

Comment: The 70 byte version will not open in the latest Chrome, but i didn't have trouble with the 138 byte version.

Comment: How do I add some random texts for testing purpose based on any of the versions above?

Comment: The correct base64 of @towi is JVBERi0xLjAKMSAwIG9iajw8L1BhZ2VzIDIgMCBSPj5lbmRvYmogMiAwIG9iajw8L0tpZHNbMyAwIFJdL0NvdW50IDE+PmVuZG9iaiAzIDAgb2JqPDwvTWVkaWFCb3hbMCAwIDMgM10+PmVuZG9iagp0cmFpbGVyPDwvUm9vdCAxIDAgUj4+Cg==

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `%%EOF` instead of `%EOF`?

Comment: The 67 bytes version causes an error in Chrome but can be opened in Adobe Reader. The 138 bytes version works fine in both.

Comment: I was unable to get any of the examples in this answer and comments to open on Mac. I used @kolypto's answer instead.

Answer (score 25):

I could not get the hello world example to open.

For a small-ish file with text content :

```
%PDF-1.2 
9 0 obj
<<
>>
stream
BT/ 9 Tf(Test)' ET
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 5 0 R
/Contents 9 0 R
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Kids [4 0 R ]
/Count 1
/Type /Pages
/MediaBox [ 0 0 99 9 ]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Pages 5 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 3 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Comment: This will not work, you need to define a font resource and select it inside the page content for the text to show up.

Comment: this file actually opens under Mac OS X El Capitan whereas the most rated answer with PDF1.0 did not.

Comment: Also opens under chrome, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjIgCjkgMCBvYmoKPDwKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJULyA5IFRmKFRlc3QpJyBFVAplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKL1BhcmVudCA1IDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgOSAwIFIKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjUgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0tpZHMgWzQgMCBSIF0KL0NvdW50IDEKL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2VzCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCA5OSA5IF0KPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1BhZ2VzIDUgMCBSCi9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCj4+CmVuZG9iagp0cmFpbGVyCjw8Ci9Sb290IDMgMCBSCj4+CiUlRU9G

Comment: @yms Do you have any example?

Comment: When I try to read this with PyPDF2: `PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: startxref not found`

Answer (score 17):

Based on all the answers here, here's the smallest PDF with text:

```py
SMALL_PDF = (
    b"%PDF-1.2 \n"
    b"9 0 obj\n<<\n>>\nstream\nBT/ 32 Tf(  YOUR TEXT HERE   )' ET\nendstream\nendobj\n"
    b"4 0 obj\n<<\n/Type /Page\n/Parent 5 0 R\n/Contents 9 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n"
    b"5 0 obj\n<<\n/Kids [4 0 R ]\n/Count 1\n/Type /Pages\n/MediaBox [ 0 0 250 50 ]\n>>\nendobj\n"
    b"3 0 obj\n<<\n/Pages 5 0 R\n/Type /Catalog\n>>\nendobj\n"
    b"trailer\n<<\n/Root 3 0 R\n>>\n"
    b"%%EOF"
)
```

As base64. Copy this and test in Chrome:

> data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjIgCjkgMCBvYmoKPDwKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJULyAzMiBUZiggIFlPVVIgVEVYVCBIRVJFICAgKScgRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iago0IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgNSAwIFIKL0NvbnRlbnRzIDkgMCBSCj4+CmVuZG9iago1IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9LaWRzIFs0IDAgUiBdCi9Db3VudCAxCi9UeXBlIC9QYWdlcwovTWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjUwIDUwIF0KPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1BhZ2VzIDUgMCBSCi9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCj4+CmVuZG9iagp0cmFpbGVyCjw8Ci9Sb290IDMgMCBSCj4+CiUlRU9G

To make the page bigger, adjust the MediaBox dimensions :)

> /MediaBox [ 0 0 250 50 ]

Comment: When I try to read this with PyPDF2: `PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadError: startxref not found`

Comment: I was able to get the base64 version to open on Mac: ` pbpaste | base64 -d > file.pdf`, and `ls -lha` showed `291B file.pdf`, and `open file.pdf` displayed a small-ish box. Thank you!

Comment: Please, center the text and fit it to the box.  : )

Comment: poppler based readers (eg `evince` and `xpdf` ) don't display the text   ghostscript based readers (eg `gv` )  display the text but also emit errors, starting with `**** Error: Cannot find a 'startxref' anywhere in the file.
               Output may be incorrect.`

Answer (score 8):

The shortest plain text I have found to be accepted by recent Acrobat (and practically no other reader) without complaint thus "readable" and "writable" as line.pdf is meaningless 38 bytes (close to Pancakes shorter 36 byte version that uses a null).

```
%PDF-1.
trailer <</Root<</Pages<<>>>>>>
```

To be acceptable to chrome it would need to be more like 76 bytes but then its rejected by acrobat etc...

```
%PDF-1.
1 0 obj<</Pages<</Kids<<>>/Count 1>>>>endobj
trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
```

I was going to give an example of what I thought was the minimal valid "universal" PDF. until I noticed that the whole ethos of using a PDF is to ensure it will render exactly the same on all devices and their PDF readers. However on cross checking my "perfectly small well formed PDF" I spotted this. TL;DR this is fixed in my personal minimal text template (at the end)

[image]

So the ground rule was **"smallest possible valid PDF"** but I consider this shortage should count as an invalid PDF since it does not adhere to the concept of "Fit for Purpose" thus the minimum PDF must itself as a minimum contain a minimum of one means of fixing a working font.

To explain my proposed solution and why its less than perfect here it is in a rough form because of cut and paste.

```
%PDF-1.0
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1/Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 595 792]>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Contents 4 0 R/Resources<<>>>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Length 58>>
stream
q
BT
/ 96 Tf
1 0 0 1 36 684 Tm
(Hello World!) Tj
ET
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000209 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 5/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
316
%%EOF
```

Whilst not defined by the rules of the *question* I have included some past experience of user problems.

The first difference you might note is media box in 2nd obj is a hybrid `MediaBox[0 0 595 792]` which is a minimax A4 width and minimax US Letter high, since otherwise the "universal page" in most countries would force a second sheet @ 100% scale printing either for too wide or too high a page definition for the locale defaults.

And the current problem is evidenced in 3rd obj as no fonts have been set for resources, thus in aiming for *minimal* the PDF, I contest without a font defined, will be Invalid.

Thus none of the answers so far including my own, appear to produce a PDF that will `"WORK"` as a "VALID" means to produce the same printout, regardless of platform or viewer.

Turning to libraries I found a 3MB zip with an exceptionally versatile windows.exe (a single file that can do most pdf functions like split merge import stamp export attachments etc.) which can take "Hello World! in a command line and produce a good working file, this is page centre zoomed in
[image]

it uses a stream for the text and its positioning, and has other conforming data like producer so I offer this as a potentially good minimal to pare down, note as presented this file will appear blank due to stream corruption from binary to text.

```
%PDF-1.7
%ÂµÂ¶

1 0 obj
<</Pages 2 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Count 1/Kids[5 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 595 792]/Type/Pages>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 101>>
stream
xœ*Tp
QÐw3P04Ò30PISp
Q01
à˜kdf¢ga¬`bhâ%ç‚ô(„”#©Aîè"EéÚlA
HW‘‚†GjNN¾Bx~QNŠ¢¦BHÈÞ@@   ÿÿFå
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Contents 4 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 792]/MediaBox[0 0 595 792]/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F0 3 0 R>>>>/Type/Page>>
endobj

6 0 obj
<</CreationDate(D:20220600600709+01'00')/ModDate(D:20220600600709+01'00')/Producer(me 2)>>
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000225 00000 n 
0000000395 00000 n 
0000000529 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Info 6 0 R/Root 1 0 R/ID[<A2A0CE5CCD9D0DABD5845AD574BF0A5C><09BF9D281BE12CB5B5933BB2B62B0D4D>]>>
startxref
636
%%EOF
```

P.S I deliberately added a non valid item so is intentionally not the minimum working answer, see if you can work out what's clearly wrong:-)

**My personal offering**
So I am often asked how to write plain text templated PDFs thus need the font to be static (Helvetica or Courier should do) and a structure that is easy to modify using windows CMD line, so this suits my purpose its now 698 bytes as shown with two place holders to show multi-line so if needed can find and replace `Helvetica` with `Courier`   (note intentional **2 spaces after** to keep byte count)

```
%PDF-1.1
%âã
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[2 0 R]>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 594 792]/Resources<</Font<</F1 3 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]>>/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/Name/F1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 5 0 R>>
stream
BT
/F1 36 Tf
1 0 0 1 255 752 Tm
48 TL
( Hello)'
(World!)'
ET
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
78
endobj
xref
0 6
0000000000 65536 f
0000000017 00000 n
0000000094 00000 n
0000000228 00000 n
0000000302 00000 n
0000000425 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 6/Info <</CreationDate(D:2023)/Producer(cmd2pdf)/Title(mini.pdf)>>/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
446
%%EOF
```

To see how this approach works in windows command line RIGHT CLICK and download as text https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/MAKE-PDF.cmd (now 200 lines long!) **NOTE** browser security may ask you to trust a cmd as download thus use .txt extension and you will still need to change properties to UNBLOCK once you are happy it should do no harm to run it!

**@mkl are you up for producing your best shot ?**

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd make a smallest pdf that displays "Hello World". The text is in the lower left corner. Sorry about the 9-point font, any larger would cost an extra byte :)

172 bytes for Adobe Reader X (if saved with linefeed-only newlines and no trailing newline or null-byte):

```
%PDF-1.
1 0 obj<</Kids[<</Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/Contents 2 0 R>>]>>endobj 2 0 obj<<>>stream
BT/ 9 Tf(Hello World)' ET
endstream
endobj trailer<</Root<</Pages 1 0 R>>>>
```

120 bytes for Chrome's builtin PDF viewer:

```
%PDF 1 0 obj<</Pages<</Kids[<</Contents<<>>stream
BT 9 Tf(Hello World)' ET endstream>>]>>>>endobj trailer<</Root 1 0 R>>
```

To easily see this in Chrome, paste this URI in the address bar (SO won't let me link to it, and it won't work at all in other browsers):

```
data:application/pdf,%25PDF%201%200%20obj%3C%3C%2FPages%3C%3C%2FKids%5B%3C%3C%2FContents%3C%3C%3E%3Estream%0ABT%209%20Tf(Hello%20World)'%20ET%20endstream%3E%3E%5D%3E%3E%3E%3Eendobj%20trailer%3C%3C%2FRoot%201%200%20R%3E%3E
```

Comment: Pretty small. ;) Not valid, though, according to the spec.

Comment: Will not open under in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Ange Albertini lecture](https://media.ccc.de/v/31c3_-_5930_-_en_-_saal_6_-_201412291400_-_funky_file_formats_-_ange_albertini#t=778), the smallest possible valid PDF is 36 bytes:

%PDF-(NULL)trailer<</Root<</Pages<<>>>>>>

Where (NULL) is the unprintable ASCII 0 character.

However, as Ange notes, while this PDF is technically valid, most PDF reader apps will regard it as invalid based on the size alone, thus failing to open it.

Comment: It is not *technically valid*, according to the specification (which is more important than a lecture) there are multiple issues, missing cross references, direct objects where indirect ones are expected, ...

Answer (score 1):

This question often comes up when testing various filetypes and there's a great repository on Github by mathiasbynens - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/small that has an archive of all types of valid files by minimum size:

Here's the example provided for PDFs:

- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/small/blob/master/pdf.pdf
  at 130 bytes

The raw content:

```
%PDF-1.
1 0 obj<</Pages 2 0 R>>endobj
2 0 obj<</Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj
3 0 obj<</Parent 2 0 R>>endobj
trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
```

And as base64 encoded:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLgoxIDAgb2JqPDwvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFI+PmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqPDwvS2lkc1szIDAgUl0vQ291bnQgMT4+ZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmo8PC9QYXJlbnQgMiAwIFI+PmVuZG9iagp0cmFpbGVyIDw8L1Jvb3QgMSAwIFI+Pg==
```

Comment: While probably accepted by multiple PDF viewers, this PDF is not valid. (Admittedly, multiple other answer to this question have the same drawback...)

Answer (score 0):

I needed a PDF version which is usable by a PDF converter (A4 format issue.. all the above constructs worked with Adobe Reader and Chrome, but not with the PDF converter which required DIN A4).
I found this site and this PDF worked fine with the PDF converter I'm using: https://help.callassoftware.com/m/73261/l/798383-how-to-create-a-simple-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

Working for a PDF related company, I know that the following content will be working pretty well. This is a valid empty A4 page:

```html
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
5 0 obj
<<
/Length 1
>>
stream
 
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Resources <<
>>
/Contents 5 0 R
/Parent 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [4 0 R]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Creator (PDF Creator http://www.pdf-tools.com)
/CreationDate (D:20150701112447+02'00')
/ModDate (D:20220607183602+02'00')
/Producer (3-Heights\222 PDF Optimization Shell 6.0.0.0 \(http://www.pdf-tools.com\))
>>
endobj
xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f
0000000226 00000 n
0000000169 00000 n
0000000275 00000 n
0000000065 00000 n
0000000015 00000 n
trailer
<<
/Size 6
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 3 0 R
/ID [<1C3500CA9F7232B97E0EF3F789E8B7F2> <254C8D153F655D49945EAD68D801E011>]
>>
startxref
505
%%EOF
```

Now using Javascript, you can embed this into your js bundle. First encode in base64 the content above, then use the encoded string and create a Blob file with it by writing:

```html
const str = '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';
const blob = new Blob([atob(str)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

Comment: Is that code block UTF-8 or some random windows code page?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at all the other answers and found that none of them would render in in ghostscript without errors or display content in readers based on poppler or libevdocument

finally I found this:

```
%PDF-1.1
%¥±ë

1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [3 0 R]
     /Count 1
     /MediaBox [0 0 300 144]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  <<  /Type /Page
      /Parent 2 0 R
      /Resources
       << /Font
           << /F1
               << /Type /Font
                  /Subtype /Type1
                  /BaseFont /Times-Roman
               >>
           >>
       >>
      /Contents 4 0 R
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj
  << /Length 55 >>
stream
  BT
    /F1 18 Tf
    0 0 Td
    (Hello World) Tj
  ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000018 00000 n 
0000000077 00000 n 
0000000178 00000 n 
0000000457 00000 n 
trailer
  <<  /Root 1 0 R
      /Size 5
  >>
startxref
565
%%EOF
```

https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0004.html

MIT license.

Comment: my problem Is i don't speak PDF  and also had not noticed that none of the examples on this page are pure ASCII. so when I copied the content and it didn't work I had no way to diagnose it. and didn't notice that the content was probably corrupt.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean some 8-bit code page. When I hear ANSI the code page I think of first is IBM-437, but that has fallen out of popularity.    interestingly your example is actually all ASCII. I am uanware of the signifigance of the second line bytes,

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about please translate "ansi" into english. I see the string "WinAnsi" in some of the other examples, are you talking about that?  "UTF-8-32"  is that the old version of UTF8 that supported 4 billion code points?

Answer (score -3):

In Java, use this:

```
 private static String samplepdf = "255044462D312E0D747261696C65723C3C2F526F6F743C3C2F50616765733C3C2F4B6964735B3C3C2F4D65646961426F785B302030203320335D3E3E5D3E3E3E3E3E3E";
```

and then

```
byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(samplepdf);
```

...

```
public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for *the smallest possible valid PDF file*; yours is not valid according to the spec.