# Null value PDF file

Tags: pdf

Anyone seen or know how to generate a completely null-value PDF file? Not a blank page, just null. Or at the most a single pixel line.

I got some software that appends a pdf file to every pdf being generated. They decided they don't want that last pdf anymore.

Rather than recompile and redistribute, I would rather drop a blank PDF in there.

However every PDF editor I uses wont let me crop it down less than 1 inch, resulting in a little 1 inch strip after the document.

Suggestions?

Comment: What software do you use to merge that PDF? If it accepted 0-page pdfs, one could simply supply such a file.

Comment: Do you have an example of a 0 page PDF? i cannot seem to find one.

Comment: *Do you have an example of a 0 page PDF* - I could try and create one. The issue is that one can argue that PDFs without pages are invalid, so there are none out there to be found.

Comment: Yes, this is what I figured, but just thought I would ask.

Comment: Does the file need to be a valid PDF? Would a zero-byte file with a .pdf extension work?

Comment: See also this question - [Whats is the smallest possible valid PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279712/what-is-the-smallest-possible-valid-pdf)