# Smallest possible invisible PDF?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

This question is related to [What is the smallest possible valid PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279712/what-is-the-smallest-possible-valid-pdf), but goes one step further: I'd like a PDF file that is as small as possible, but also **invisible**.

That means:

- it contains no text or other objects (or if that's not possible, only completely transparent ones), and
- it has no background (or if that's not possible, a completely transparent background).

When I open this file in a compliant PDF viewer, the background color of the viewer panel should show through completely, and when I embed it in a document on top of other elements, only these other elements should show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF pages have no background color by default (if you need an explicit background you have to draw a colored rectangle that covers the entire page).
PDF viewers will use a default white background to simulate a paper page, so the actual background depends on the PDF viewer.
When you place a PDF page on top of another one it will not block the underlying content if it does not have an explicit background.

Comment: Do I assume correctly that the minimal PDF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17280876/2056067) has no such explicit background?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The page in that PDF file has no content at all.

Comment: According to ISO 32000-1: *The notion of current page is generalized to refer to a transparency group consisting of the entire stack of objects placed on the page, **composited with a backdrop that is pure white and fully opaque***. Thus, PDF pages by default have a white backdrop, they are not transparent. Only if you don't treat pages as pages, the situation differs: *In contexts where a PDF page is treated as a piece of artwork to be placed on some other page it is treated not as a page but as a group, whose backdrop may be defined differently from that of a page.*