# json to pdf in javasript without any libraries

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there any method that may be able to convert JSON data to pdf with using only pure `Javascript` , without using any libraries or packages

There is a requirement to create a single html page (done with help of webpack) for offline work . so I need to download some json as pdf and should not not use any libraries.

Comment: Why do you want to put JSON in a PDF in the first place?

Comment: The client needs to download data as pdf also

Comment: @ ndc85430   any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unfairly said in comments

> no, until you write your own text/pdf parser. possible but not likely within my remaining lifetime,

So your challenge is to see (fast as you can) if you can use your Javascript coding skills to convert from raw:-

```
   {
        "text": {
            "text": "Hello World!",
            "points": 48 ,
            "x": 36 ,
            "y": 684
        }
    }
```

into this, and adapt it for other json objects, so perhaps add a page definition above to show text is on page 1 with a media box so as to relate the xy values to that page. Generally write the page structure first then the resources such as fonts then the text mapped to font and position.

```
%PDF-1.0
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1/Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 595 792]>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Contents 4 0 R/Resources<<>>>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Length 58>>
stream
q
BT
/ 96 Tf
1 0 0 1 36 684 Tm
(Hello World!) Tj
ET
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000209 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 5/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
316
%%EOF
```

Note there is no font so this example is just step one, the next step is much harder and that is how to include the font description, so for a hint see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748286/10802527

HOWEVER if you write JS you are writing a 3rd party library yourself and by far the simplest is use a single line command So I have a one line txt2pdf cmd that will take argument "Hello World!" and echo it into this format then display as pdf on screen:-

```
{"pages":{"1":{"content":{"text":[{"value":"############","anchor":"center","font":{"name":"Helvetica","size":12}}]}}}}
```

`echo {"pages":{"1":{"content":{"text":[{"value":"%~1","anchor":"center","font":{"name":"Helvetica","size":12}}]}}}}>hello.json && pdfcpu create hello.json hello.pdf && hello.pdf`

[image]

So contrary to using raw JS I suggest there is already an exceptionally very good  [Apache-2.0 license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) 3 MB cross platform API/CLI library that converts Json to PDF. So above one liner uses amazing tiny powerful https://pdfcpu.io/