# How to create a PDF file from any Base64 string?

Tags: javascript

I want to input any Base64 string to function and get the PDF from there. So tried this way, It download the PDF but there is a error

"Failed to load PDF document."

**This is the way I tried,**

```
let data = "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=" //hello world

 var bufferArray = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(data);


    var binary_string = window.atob(data)
    var len = bufferArray.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    let blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' })
  
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
    window.open(url);


 //convert base64 string to arraybuffer
 base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var bString = window.atob(data);
    var bLength = bString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(bLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < bLength; i++) {
        var ascii = bString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
};
```

Comment: What is `this.base64ToArrayBuffer`?

Comment: sorry for that - I have edited the question @CryptoAlgorithm

Comment: I'm inclined to think that its something wrong with the 2 stages of conversion youre doing before finally creating the `Blob`

Comment: @ericmp - I tried that it didn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/Janaka_Ravindra/5fc8poy9/1/)

Comment: @CryptoAlgorithm Do you have any idea what is the mistake happen before create the blob

Comment: @jhon true, i delete the comment

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is not pdf so hello.b64 will never morph into hello.pdf

It needs a pdf header page and trailer in decimal bytes, those cannot be easily added as base64 object wrapping as too many variables.

The text/pdf needs careful script as text to wrap around the hello text see hello example https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748286/10802527

So as Base64 for example
**JVBER**i0xLjIgDQo5IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KQlQvIDMyIFRmKCAg**SGVsbG8gV29ybGQgICAp**JyBFVA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQ0KL1BhcmVudCA1IDAgUg0KL0NvbnRlbnRzIDkgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0tpZHMgWzQgMCBSIF0NCi9Db3VudCAxDQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCAyNTAgNTAgXQ0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9QYWdlcyA1IDAgUg0KL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cNCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCnRyYWlsZXINCjw8DQovUm9vdCAzIDAgUg0KPj4NCiUlRU9G

```html
<iframe type="application/pdf" width="95%" height=150 src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjIgDQo5IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KQlQvIDMyIFRmKCAgSGVsbG8gV29ybGQgICApJyBFVA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQ0KL1BhcmVudCA1IDAgUg0KL0NvbnRlbnRzIDkgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0tpZHMgWzQgMCBSIF0NCi9Db3VudCAxDQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCAyNTAgNTAgXQ0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9QYWdlcyA1IDAgUg0KL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cNCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCnRyYWlsZXINCjw8DQovUm9vdCAzIDAgUg0KPj4NCiUlRU9G">frame</iframe>
```

Try above but may be blocked by security it will look like this for some users but not ALL !

[image]
[image]

In comments you asked how text could be manipulated in java script, and my stock answer is java script cannot generally be easily used to build PDF or edit Base64 content. However if you have prepared placeholders it can be changed by find and replace. But must be done with care as the total file length should never be changed.

As an example take the above as a prior template and switch the content to.

JVBERi0xLjIgDQo5IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KQlQvIDMyIFRmKCAg**RmFyZS10aGVlLXdlbGwp**JyBFVA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQ0KL1BhcmVudCA1IDAgUg0KL0NvbnRlbnRzIDkgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0tpZHMgWzQgMCBSIF0NCi9Db3VudCAxDQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCAyNTAgNTAgXQ0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9QYWdlcyA1IDAgUg0KL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cNCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCnRyYWlsZXINCjw8DQovUm9vdCAzIDAgUg0KPj4NCiUlRU9G

So by find and replace `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQgICAp` with `RmFyZS10aGVlLXdlbGwp` we get a text change:- (it is important the string length is a multiple of 4 and the length is the same)

```html
<iframe type="application/pdf" width="95%" height=150 src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjIgDQo5IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KPj4NCnN0cmVhbQ0KQlQvIDMyIFRmKCAgRmFyZS10aGVlLXdlbGwpJyBFVA0KZW5kc3RyZWFtDQplbmRvYmoNCjQgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZQ0KL1BhcmVudCA1IDAgUg0KL0NvbnRlbnRzIDkgMCBSDQo+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0tpZHMgWzQgMCBSIF0NCi9Db3VudCAxDQovVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMNCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCAyNTAgNTAgXQ0KPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMyAwIG9iag0KPDwNCi9QYWdlcyA1IDAgUg0KL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cNCj4+DQplbmRvYmoNCnRyYWlsZXINCjw8DQovUm9vdCAzIDAgUg0KPj4NCiUlRU9G">frame</iframe>
```

and the result be

[image]

There are strict rules to be followed when using this method:-
`Hello World   )` is the template, note the inclusion of white space before the `)` limit thus
`Fare-thee-well)` is as far as substitution is allowed in this case
so source field must be pre-planned to be big enough for largest replacement and is based on a plain text length of multiples of 3 (matches base64 blocks of 4)

Comment: My problem is have a any way to create this PDF base64 string using javascript

Comment: Thanks for these informations